# Como eu posso combinar múltiplos histogramas em um único plot?

Tags: python

Eu tenho dados temporais de 52 dias e para cada um desses dias eu criei um histograma 2D. Agora eu preciso combinar esses histogramas em um só, mas não sei exatamente como eu faria isso. Alguém já passou por esse problema e conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: consegue explicar melhor o problema? como vc armazena esses histogramas e qual o resultado de saida seria interessante você detalhar.

Comment: estava armazenando em uma lista, mas não sei se essa é a melhor alternativa. O resultado de saída é um histograma 2D pra cada conjunto de dados

Comment: se é uma imagem vc pode usar o vstack do numpy ou o concatenate https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/opencv-combine-images/.
Agora se vc tem os dados que geram os histogramas vc pode sobrepor eles

Comment: Sobrepor você diz juntá-los em um array e fazer um único plot, certo?